# fadeout text at a lower speed

Tags: java, text, processing, fade

I want to make a group of array fade out until the last array object in this group was appended. And I use millis() to make every three object fadeout at a slower speed! So I create a function called `boolean timelag(int time, int number)`and each time I pass the time and sequence number into it and expect it will fadeout after 2 seconds after every third object was created, but seems that nothing happened

```
void draw() {
  background(255, 255, 255);

  for (int i=0; i<zoog.length; i++) {
    zoog[i].jiggle();
    zoog[i].display();
    if(i%3 ==0 && i>=3){
       time = millis();
       timelag(time,i);
    }    
  }
  if(fadeout){
      zoog[thatnumber].disappear();
      zoog[thatnumber-1].disappear();
      zoog[thatnumber-2].disappear(); 
    }
}
```

My timelag function:

```
boolean timelag(int time, int number){
  int thattime = time;
  if(millis()-thattime>2000){
    thatnumber = number;
    fadeout = true;
  }
  else 
   fadeout = false;


  return fadeout;
}
```

The whole code is here

```
Zoog[]zoog = new Zoog[1];
float count=0;
int xpos =0;
int ypos =0;
String message="haha";
int ntextsize = 20;
int nopacity =200;
int thistime = 0;
int thiscount = 0;
int time =0;
int number =0;
boolean fadeout = false;
int thatnumber=0;


//Zoog zoog;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  xpos = int(random(width/2-200, width/2+40));
  ypos = int(random(height/2, height/2-40));
  zoog[0] = new Zoog(xpos, ypos, message, nopacity);
}

void draw() {
  background(255, 255, 255);

  for (int i=0; i<zoog.length; i++) {
    zoog[i].jiggle();
    zoog[i].display();
    if(i%3 ==0 && i>=3){
       time = millis();
       timelag(time,i);
    }    
  }
  if(fadeout){
      zoog[thatnumber].disappear();
      zoog[thatnumber-1].disappear();
      zoog[thatnumber-2].disappear(); 
    }
}


void mousePressed() {
  count = count + 1;
  // int thiscount = 0;
  if (count%3 ==0) {
    xpos=int(random(30, width-30));
    ypos=int(random(10, height-10));
  }
  else {
    ypos = ypos+50;
  }


nopacity = int(random(100, 255));
// text(message, xpos, ypos);
Zoog b = new Zoog(xpos, ypos, message, nopacity);
zoog =(Zoog[]) append(zoog, b);

}

boolean timelag(int time, int number){
  int thattime = time;
  if(millis()-thattime>2000){
    thatnumber = number;
    fadeout = true;
  }
  else 
   fadeout = false;


  return fadeout;
}

class Zoog {
  int x;
  int y;
  String thatmessage;

  int opaci =0;

  Zoog(int xpo, int ypo, String thismessage, int opa) {
    x = xpo;
    y = ypo;
    thatmessage = thismessage;

    opaci = opa;
  }

  void jiggle() {

    x = x+int(random(-2, 2));
    y = y+int(random(-2, 2));
  }

  void display() {

    fill(0, opaci);
    text(thatmessage, x, y);
    print("x position is "+ x);
    print("y position is "+y);
  }

  void disappear() {
    for (int j=0; j<255; j++) {
      opaci = opaci -j;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can we see the whole code?

Comment: Sure, Done editing!!!

Comment: I sugest you try to implement the suggestions in the response of your first post before moving ahead. The ArrayList and everything, as it will make your code much easier to read and all. The for loop in the disappear() method makes no sense, also the way you are using key pressed... Try the suggestion of the first post. than move on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First time i read the other post I misunderstood your goal. Anyway i've made a little tweak in your code that might help you understanding the way to go. BUT i did not moved it to an ArrayList, so this code below, kind of sucks... It can only, maybe, help you get things clear...

```
Zoog[]zoog = new Zoog[1];
float count=0;
int xpos =0;
int ypos =0;
String message="haha";
int ntextsize = 20;
int nopacity =200;
int thistime = 0;
int thiscount = 0;
//Zoog zoog;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  xpos = int(random(width/2-200, width/2+40));
  ypos = int(random(height/2, height/2-40));
  zoog[0] = new Zoog(xpos, ypos, message, nopacity);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);

  for (int i=0; i<zoog.length; i++) {
    zoog[i].jiggle();
    zoog[i].display();  }
}




void mousePressed() {
  count = count + 1;
  // int thiscount = 0;
  if (count%3 ==0) {
    xpos=int(random(30, width-30));
    ypos=int(random(10, height-10));
  }
  else {
    ypos = ypos+50;
    //   thiscount = thiscount +1;
    //   thistime = millis();
    //  }
  }


  nopacity = int(random(100, 255));
  text(message, xpos, ypos);
  Zoog b = new Zoog(mouseX, mouseY, message, nopacity);
  zoog = (Zoog[]) append(zoog, b);

  zoog[zoog.length -2].disappear = true;
}





class Zoog {
  int x;
  int y;
  String thatmessage;
  boolean disappear;

  int opaci =0;

  Zoog(int xpo, int ypo, String thismessage, int opa) {
    x = xpo;
    y = ypo;
    thatmessage = thismessage;

    opaci = opa;
  }

  void jiggle() {

    x = x+int(random(-2, 2));
    y = y+int(random(-2, 2));
  }

  void display() {
    if(disappear)
    disappear();
    fill(0, opaci);
    text(thatmessage, x, y);
  }

  void disappear() {

    opaci-=0.5;

  }
}
```

Comment: I have never seen the zoog[zoog.length -2].disappear = true;which means I can run the disappear() function, It is pretty neat, thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

I assume that when you wrote...

```
if(fadeout) { ... }
```

you meant...

```
if(timelag()) { ... }
```

in your timelag function it's much more readable and faster(if even minutely) to just return true or false from the function rather than returning a variable, unless that variable is needed throughout your project over and over, which it doesn't seem like it is and if it is the function that changes it usually isn't needed to return a value unless you're checking the boolean of whether or not the change happened.

```
boolean timelag(int time, int number){
  //int thattime = time; //You also don't need to create this you 
  //can simply use the time you're getting in the boolean statement
  if(millis()-time>2000){
    thatnumber = number;
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

also, if you're trying to fix how long it takes for each zoog to fade out you need to give them all a number and then decrease that number each time the disappear function is called. Take the for loop out of the disappear and just have it subtract a unit from it each call in the draw loop.

```
void disappear() {
   opacity -= somenumber //somenumber is usually something small and you can tweak it. 
   if (opacity == 0) {
      dead = true;
   }
}
```

You can think of the draw loop as your for loop. If you embed too many singular for loops it'll slow down the flow of your program. Right now, you probably don't even see them fading out and you probably don't get rid of them with the way the code is written right now.

And when you're testing it you can tweak that number until you find the sweet spot. If you want an amazing overview of all these concepts you can take a look [here](http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-4-particle-systems/). Shiffman really goes deep into each aspect we're talking about here and it's short and fun to read.